# Resistances in a circular loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

I have no idea what formula I'm supposed to use.I just want to know the concept that would allow me to get the answer. I know basic concepts of electricity like charge, currents, etc., but as far resistances go I know only about series and parallel. I tried looking for resistances in a circular loop but I didn't understand what was being explained. Also I didn't find any concept that helped me understand what was to be done, probably because I didn't understand them.I used some help from a different question and got the resistances but my answer wasnt correct.

Comment: its not a part of my homework or anything. i just wanted to solve an old paper. but im stuck

Comment: Even if it's not a homework assignment, the homework policy still applies. Please see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: but cant i atleast get the concept that applies?

Comment: You're allowed to ask homework questions, but only if you put in some effort to show us what you understand and what you don't. At the moment nobody can answer your question, because we don't know which of the concepts you are familiar with and which you aren't. If you can edit it to explain precisely where you're stuck, then it will be on topic.

Comment: okay thanks thats what i wanted to know.i know basic concepts of electricity like charge,currents,etc but as far resistances go i know only about series and parallel.i tried looking for resistances in a circular loop but i didnt understand what was being explained.also i didnt find any concept that helped me understand what was to be done probably because i didnt understand them.

Comment: It's better to put those details in the question instead of in a comment. (I've done it for you this time.) I'll give you a hint to solve your problem: you probably already have all the concepts you need. Have another look at the diagram and see if there's a way to think about it in terms of series or parallel resistors. (You will also need to know about resistivity, though, which is different from resistance.)

Comment: It's better to read about it and ask a question if you have difficulty understanding something. People generally don't like questions where the answer can easily be found on something like Wikipedia.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78771/magnitude-of-magnetic-field-at-the-center-of-circular-wire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resistance can be taken as $$R = \rho \frac{l}{a}$$ where $rho$ is resistivity, $l$ is length of resistor and $a$ is cross sectional area of the resistor.

The above is asking you for a ratio of $R_1:R_2$ and you are given all the numbers in the question.  Shapes within a circuit diagram can typically be ignored, the diagrams are only symbolic to inform you of how the pieces are connected.